# Issue with black line through images in IE9 (own website)

Tags: image, web, internet-explorer-9

I am having issues with weird black lines being displayed through a website I work on in IE 9. I have tried turning off compression but I am at a loss as to what to do about this. Has anyone seen this or can you give me some suggestions?

Web page: http://3dprinterhub.com

IE9 Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uupuz.png

Comment: Does it show up on other versions of Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "weird black lines" are coming from the A links in your menu.

You have hidden the actual text in the menu by using "span.help" with "visibility: hidden", but the actual A links themselves are still visible (hence the visible lines).

If you add "visibility: hidden" or "text-decoration: none" to your "a.nav_button" and "a.nav_buttons" CSS rules, then the underlines will disappear.